# integrated google search box

Tags: javascript, html

I want to integrate google search in website such way that whenever we search in google the search box should show like below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<form class="search-box" action="https://example.com/search.htm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <button type="submit" class="search-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
</form>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
```

to replace with this google search coding:

```html
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=da0913cf3d0f12b51"></script>
<div class="gcse-search"></div>
```

Comment: you could use the google search api https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: checked, but how to integrated into html form?

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: totally no idea how to replace the form format with  google search api....pls help or provide any example....easier to understand and modify the code with example.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Why not open your sourcecode in any editor, remove the code from the first snippet, and add the code from the second snippet?

Comment: tried, it work for only insert code from the second snippet.....but other component unable to work.....you can see this to get better scenario......http://jpjplatenumber.com/ on the menu bar.